# Features show strong interaction, but can't build model!

Tags: machine-learning

I have a dataset which looks as follows, all columns are categorical.

```
ad  feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4   ...
 1      0       2       1         2       ...
 0      2       1       3         0       ...
 etc
```

ad is a binary outcome variable (diagnosis with alzheimer's disease) which is dependent on the features. Rougly 40% of rows have ad = 1. All features are shown to correlate with ad. Many of the features are shown to interact, this was studied with a chi-squared test (highly significant p-values were attained, with bonferroni correction).

The features are *not* independent, e.g males are more likely to smoke, some genetic variants are more likely to occur together.

Based on the above I would have assumed that building a model to predict ad = 1 or 0 would be very easy, but I am struggling to get this done.

An additional problem is that there are some missing values in the feature set.

Which modelling approaches do you think would be most effective (and why) based on the dataset at hand: binary outcome variable with equal distribution of values, categorical features which are not independent (with missing values).

I have tried some approaches myself, but I won't bias your answers by describing my approach in this question.
Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: This is unanswerable at present. Why are you "struggling"? What did you try? In what sense didn't it work? Etc. Note that, even if this becomes clear enough to be answered, "what models should I try building next, and why" is too broad a question. So you will need to narrow that down as well.

Comment: I have tried several models, but I didn't want to bias the answers by suggesting that some method do not work (they may have not worked because of my bad application). I guess to narrow down my question I should have said: "What models would be best for predicting a categorical (binary) variable with roughly equal distribution of outcomes, with categorical features, the features are not independent and there are some missing values in the feature set". Thanks for your input, let me know if I need any more clarification!

Comment: @gung thanks for the response, updated the question to reflect your advice, also see comment above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following come to mind:

1. Decision trees/random forests
2. Support vector machines
3. K Nearest Neighbor

You will have to play around with and tune the models to see if they work, but you might get some good results. Given that Alzheimer's is pretty rare, it might take a lot of turning and domain knowledge (e.g. in the form of kernel functions for SVMs) to do better than just always predicting 0, but hopefully these models can get you started.

Comment: Kudos for mentioning the rarity of alzheimer's but in the dataset roughly 40% of rows have ad = 1.

Comment: Nice. In that case, I wouldn't be surprised if one of the basic models that I mentioned or something else got you pretty good accuracy. If it were me, I'd start with a decision tree since it can give you easily interpretable results. From there you can try to build out something more complex if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try decision tree, it will give you insights about your data and idea where you can head next. You should carry out bivariate analysis with target and see how the event rate is changing across different categories. You can also make 3d plots to understand interactions for the variables which you think might not be very independent.

Comment: Sounds like good advice, especially the 3d plots. But would a decision tree be able to include the information on 'interactions'? What I mean by interactions is: when features3 = 2 and feature4 = 1 there is a higher than expected chance of ad = 1 (this is studied by a chi-squared test).

Comment: Decision tree can give you fair idea about how the population is splitting up. If you believe that certain variables are likely to have interaction, they would end up in same branch. But again, you have to try multiple things, to come up with best models. You can try creating different features out of your data, like: male_ind=1 and smoke_ind=1(just an example). you can also plot histograms for event rate for all combinations of  gender*smoke(similar for others). You need to make multiple hypothesis and validate them by different methods.